# How to disassembler exe file With API windows?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, assembly

I wrote a program that opens the exe files. I want that program to read some specific assembly instructions with their addresses in an exe file. for example JAM or Call.
so, what API functions should I use. if you know any other sources that can be useful tell me ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read code in a **Windows PE file** (Portable Executable) you will first have to find the code section.

How to find this depends whether the exe is a 32-bit or 64-bit one (although they're pretty much the same for their internal structure), but I recommend you **studying the PE format**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx

After that you will have to find the address in which your call code or whatever you want resides. What do you want to do with that binary code is up to you, if you intend to translate it into asm human-readable code you will need a translator (or code one up by yourself... pretty hard for a beginner) such as [distorm](http://ragestorm.net/distorm/) (GPL and commercial license).

I hope this got you started to what you want to do.

Comment: i did what you said. i have problem with translation.i don't know how a true disassemble works

Comment: You have hex code that you want to interpret as asm code? I suggest you to use the library I linked, it's easy and effective. Otherwise start from here (assuming x64 system): http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Comment: i read the exe file and i have them in memory  and that is the Hex.

Comment: and i have the addresses of start sections

Comment: Then use the library I linked. I won't write that again..

Comment: i'll use that and tell you the result. thanks buddy ;)

Answer (score 0):

A very good start will be to use a disassembly library, [Capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/) is one of them for example but more exists.

Then you will need to parse the PE executable format to extract the code to send to your disassembly library...

But in that domain libraries also exists, for example [radare](http://www.radare.org/y/?p=features) supporting most architectures and format (And it can be used with multiple disassembly libraries, including Capstone)